# Replace special characters with set from Windows cmd

Tags: sed

I need to replace the string `"\\"` (double quote backslash backslash double quote) with `""` (double quote double quote).

The following is an example of the data to be manipulated:

```
","","","\\","",0,
```

Result needs to be:

```
","","","","",0,
```

I cannot just remove the `\\` as the data will occasionally include values on either side of the backslashes as it is being used to represent a carriage return. For example I would want to ignore this occurrence of the backslashes as they are preceded by data rather than just double quotes.

```
","","","123\\456","",0,
```

Attempted to no avail:

```
sed "s/\"\\\"//g" atm-file.csv >atm-file.txt
sed "s:”\\”:"":g" atm-file.csv > atm-file.txt
```

Comment: You seem to have curly quotes in your very last example - is this intentional?

Comment: No - a by-product of the text editor I was using at the time.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, it worked for me when I tried it:

```
sed 's|\"\\\\\"|\"\"|g' atm-file.csv >atm-file.txt
```

If it doesn't work, you may need to provide a link to your `.csv` file.
EDIT
I now see that my `sed` command is essentially the same thing as what is in your question. Please provide a link to a copy of the `.csv` file.